# How to correctly import from apache commons in Java

Tags: java, classpath, apache-commons-math

First of all, forgive my poor programming skills.
I recently downloaded commons math 2.2, which came with 3 .jar files:
commons-math-2.2-javadoc.jar
commons-math-2.2-sources.jar
commons-math-2.2.jar

I want to use the normal distribution methods but I don't know how to get access to them. http://commons.apache.org/math/api-2.1/index.html

I'm using drJava on mac. What import or package statements do I need?  Do I need to change anything in the drJava preferences?  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

- add the `commons-math-2.2.jar` to the classpath
- import whichever class you need: `import org.apache.commons.math.*` (avoid the star though - list all the classes the you import. A good IDE should offer you to organize your imports)

Comment: Remember, I have poor programming skills.  How do I "add the commons-math-2.2.jar to the classpath"?  How do I even know what my class path is?

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/classpath.html But there should be some menu option in your drJava. I have never used it, so I don't know where exactly it is.